F2 score pycaret
I want to add the metric F2 score in pycaret but it's not working when I run the column F2 is 0 but I tried without pycaret and it worked.
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, fbeta_score

def f2_score(y_true, y_pred):
  return fbeta_score(y_true, y_pred, beta=2)

f2_scorer = make_scorer(f2_score, greater_is_better=True)
clf1 = setup(df, target= target_column, train_size=0.8, fold=5)

add_metric('lol', 'AUPRC', average_precision_score, target='pred_proba')
add_metric('fbeta', 'F2', f2_score, target='pred_proba')

best = compare_models(include=\['rf', 'xgboost'\], fold=5)


Please clarify what "not working" and "it worked" mean. Is an error reported? Is there value evidence that a value is not updated?
